# Upload Image with Axios Post request

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I am trying to make a post request to an api to upload a user image and send it to the api for profile settings.But i always receive "the image field is required" error although I send formData object. Where is my mistake in below codes ? Please help. below are my codes. Get request is working fine but post request is not working

```
src - api.js
export const updateProfileImage = (formData) => {
    return axios.post('/my/profile/image', formData, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
    });
};
```

```
src - redux - extraActions.js
export const updateProfileImage = createAsyncThunk(
    'profileCreation/updateProfileImage',
    async (formData, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        return handleApiCall(() => getProfileApi.updateProfileImage(formData), rejectWithValue);
    },
);
```

```
src - redux - slice.js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { updateProfileImage } from './extraActions';
import { REDUX_LOADING_STATUS } from '@constants/status';
import {
    applyFulfilledStatus,
    applyRejectedStatus,
    applyPendingStatus,
    errorMessage,
    successMessage,
} from '@utils/redux';

const initialState = {
    userInfo: {},
    status: REDUX_LOADING_STATUS,
    statusCode: '',
    message: '',
};

export const profileCreationSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'profile',
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(updateProfileImage.pending, (state) => {
            console.info('profile image is being sent to api...');
            applyPendingStatus(state);
        });

        builder.addCase(updateProfileImage.rejected, (state, action) => {
            applyRejectedStatus(state, action);
            errorMessage(action.payload.message);
        });

        builder.addCase(updateProfileImage.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            applyFulfilledStatus(state, action);
            successMessage(action.payload.message);
        });
    },
});

export default profileCreationSlice.reducer;
```

```
src - containers- ProfileContainer - generalContainer - index.js
import React from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Button } from 'antd';
import styles from './index.module.less';
import { updateProfileImage } from '@redux/slices/profileCreation/extraActions';

export default function GeneralContainer() {
    const [profileImage, setProfileImage] = useState();


    function updateProfileImg(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('profileImage', profileImage);
        dispatch(
            updateProfileImage({
                image: formData,
                // image is my api key
            }),
        );
    }
    return (
        <Row className={styles.rowGeneral}>
            <Col span={24} className={styles.subtitleCol}>
                <h4>Profile Settings</h4>
            </Col>
            <Col span={24}>
                <form onSubmit={updateProfileImg}>
                    <div className={styles.profileImage}>
                        <img
                            src={profileImage ? URL.createObjectURL(profileImage) : userInfo?.thumb}
                        />
                        <p>Profile Photo</p>
                    </div>
                    <label htmlFor="img" className={styles.uploadLabel}>
                        Upload a photo:
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="file"
                        id="img"
                        name="img"
                        hidden
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            setProfileImage(e.target.files[0]);
                        }}
                    />
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    );
}
```

Comment: I am also having the same error. I sent the data with FormData but it keep saying filed is required. In my case none of the post request with FormData is working. Did you find any solution or its bug with the package itself?

Answer (score 2):

those we are using axios version 0.25 or 0.26, solution is

```
axios.post(url, formData, {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
  transformRequest: formData => formData,
})
```

from axios version 0.27, it works as usual.